# spring like drawing in c#

Tags: c#, math, drawing, system.drawing, shapes

How to draw the spring like shape using c# drawing class

[alt text http://img812.imageshack.us/img812/373/spring.jpg](http://img812.imageshack.us/img812/373/spring.jpg)

Comment: Any specific part you are having problems with?

Comment: no i dont know how to start and where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a math problem than a C# one. What you want is to derive a [Parametric equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation) for the curve you wish to draw.

With that go and fill an array of Point objects with values for the parametric equation on a certain interval with a certain step (the smaller the step the more the final drawing will look like the actual shape). Then you can use g.DrawLines ([MSDN: DrawLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ewkcdb3.aspx)) to draw the actual curve on a surface.

You can edit the width, color and other properties of the line by modifying parameters of the Pen object.

Your actual code would look like this:

```
void DrawSpring (Graphics g)
{
    List<Point> points = new List<Point>();

    double step = 0.01;
    for(double t = -2; t < 2; t += step)
    {
        Point p = new Point();
        p.X = XPartOfTheEquation(t);
        p.Y = YPartOfTheEquation(t);

        points.Add(p);
     }

    g.DrawLines(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 2f), points.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you'd need to think of a formula that would represent the spring. You could draw a circle and as you're going around it, let the X increase a bit. For instance:

```
        for (double i = 0; i < 50; i += 0.01)
        {
            int x = (int)(Math.Sin(i) * 10 + i * 3);
            int y =(int)(Math.Cos(i) * 10 + 50);
        }
```

See the `i` variable there as time, and the result `x` and `y` the coordinates to draw; you'd traverse the path of the spring in small steps.

You could then create a new `Bitmap` and use the `SetPixel` method on those coordinates, and in the `OnPaint` method of your form, draw the bitmap on it.

If you're any good with math (I'm not :P) you might be able to only plot pixels inside the bitmap - the above example doesn't solve the problem of the minimum and maximum values for `i`.

Comment: With setPixel approach the step will have to be very small in order to create a continuous drawing (spring), and some tweaking will be required in order to avoid pixel art :) With the drawlines approach (see my answer) a larger step will be sufficient for producing a convincing shape.

Comment: Agreed :] There's lots of things to play around with, I could imagine calculating only one "circle" and copying it to speed things up.