# How to draw a spring in C# wpf using xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can i make a spring from xaml code..i was thinking of using bezier segments...but i don't know how...

```
         ` <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Canvas.Left="244.77" Canvas.Top="45.655" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="31.6" Stretch="Fill" Width="25.658">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-89.333"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathGeometry.Figures>
                        <PathFigureCollection>
                            <PathFigure StartPoint="10,100">
                                <PathFigure.Segments>
                                    <PathSegmentCollection>
                                        <BezierSegment Point1="100,0" Point2="200,200" Point3="300,100" />
                                    </PathSegmentCollection>
                                </PathFigure.Segments>
                            </PathFigure>
                        </PathFigureCollection>
                    </PathGeometry.Figures>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Canvas.Left="244.77" Canvas.Top="45.655" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="31.6" Stretch="Fill" Width="25.658">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-89.333"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathGeometry.Figures>
                        <PathFigureCollection>
                            <PathFigure StartPoint="10,100">
                                <PathFigure.Segments>
                                    <PathSegmentCollection>
                                        <BezierSegment Point1="100,0" Point2="200,200" Point3="300,100" />
                                    </PathSegmentCollection>
                                </PathFigure.Segments>
                            </PathFigure>
                        </PathFigureCollection>
                    </PathGeometry.Figures>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>`
```

those are two but i want a single one that contains like five of those little one..and maybe look more natural...

Comment: If you look at your xaml from afar, it looks like a spring! =D On a serious note, have you tried search first? [Click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3412189/1997232), [click](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/spring/)...

Comment: i saw that...but the thing is i don't want a c# coded spring...i want it in xaml...and i know it looks like a spring but there are 2 bezier segments there and i want only one with 5 of those little bezier segment

Comment: Try to draw it in *Blend*, perhaps there are some tools to optimize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you find a picture that's tiling well. Then you can draw a line and use a VisualBrush with the image as ImageSource. That should work well:

[How to set a .PNG image as a TILED background image for my WPF Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725184/how-to-set-a-png-image-as-a-tiled-background-image-for-my-wpf-form)

Added an sample:

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="272" Margin="70,54,0,0" StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="12.166">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <ImageBrush
                Viewport="0,0,1,0.1"
                TileMode="FlipY"
                AlignmentX="Left"
                AlignmentY="Top"
                ImageSource="helix.png" Stretch="Uniform" />
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>            
</Grid>
```

Looks like this:
[image]

When using this png:
[image]

I am sure you will find a better tiling image... ;)